# lowercase routes and exclude Index

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working with asp.net mvc 4 and have some issues around routing.

- how do I ensure that all routes generated on the site via url's etc to be lower case? I have set `RouteTable.Routes.LowercaseUrls = true;` but the urls are still being generated in uppercase etc. Am I missing something?
- I want to tweak my routes so that I no longer have /Home/About/Index to /Home/About - so that the Index is dropped when the route is generated - how can this be done.

Finally, this is my route configuration.

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "home/{action}", 
    new { controller = "About" });
```

Comment: Where are you setting `LowercaseUrls = true`? Normally that is in the `RegisterRoutes` method in `RouteConfig.cs`.

Comment: This is set when the application starts up.

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this, when I don't use UrlRewrite in IIS to handle lowercase routes

Install this NuGet package: http://lowercaseroutesmvc.codeplex.com/

```
using LowercaseRoutesMVC
 ...

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
   routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

   routes.MapRouteLowercase( // changed from routes.MapRoute
       "Default",
       "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
}
```

Check the accepted answer on this SO post describing UrlRewrite Lowercase Urls [IIS URL rewrite module url's to lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241378/iis-url-rewrite-module-urls-to-lowercase)