# routes.LowercaseUrls and routes.AppendTrailingSlash not work in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, maproute

I am developing mv4 website,

would you please tell me why these command do not do anything in my application when I write them into RouteConfig:

```
routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
routes.AppendTrailingSlash = true;
```

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First up, you need to be generating the routes via something `@Html.ActionLink`, `@Url.Action` or similar for anything to work. It's not a magic bullet.

From MSDN:

**AppendTrailingSlash**

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether trailing slashes are added
>   when virtual paths are normalized.

([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.appendtrailingslash(v=vs.110).aspx))

**LowercaseUrls**

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether URLs are converted to lower case when virtual paths are normalized.

([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.lowercaseurls(v=vs.110).aspx))

The URL format is ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator)):

> scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]**path**[?query][#fragment]

The portion of that this affects is the path portion and that only. Any query-string portion is unaffected. AppendTrailingSlash adds a / to the end of the path portion.

So for this code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("About this Website", "About")
```

With the route parameters set to `routes.LowercaseUrls = true;` and `routes.AppendTrailingSlash = true;` it would generate:

```
<a href="/home/about/">About this Website</a>
```

With the route parameters set to `routes.LowercaseUrls = false;` and `routes.AppendTrailingSlash = true;` it would generate:

```
<a href="/Home/About/">About this Website</a>
```

With the route parameters set to `routes.LowercaseUrls = true;` and `routes.AppendTrailingSlash = false;` it would generate:

```
<a href="/home/about">About this Website</a>
```

With the route parameters set to `routes.LowercaseUrls = false;` and `routes.AppendTrailingSlash = false;` it would generate:

```
<a href="/Home/About">About this Website</a>
```

For this code:

```
@url.action("someAction","someController",new{Name=Test})
```

With the route parameters set to `routes.LowercaseUrls = true;` and `routes.AppendTrailingSlash = true;` it would generate:

```
/somecontroller/someaction/?Name=Test
```

**Some bugs that you could be hitting:**
There is a [bug with areas](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/685) in MVC 4, in regards to lowercase Urls.

The NuGet package [LowercaseRoutesMVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LowercaseRoutesMVC/1.0.3) preports to fix this bug.

---

**Possible solutions to lowercase URLs on your Application**

If you're wanting to alter behavior outside of the app, consider using something like [Url Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) for IIS which can transform your URLs. Example of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241378/iis-url-rewrite-module-urls-to-lowercase).

Comment: You mean if I have some link like : `<a href="@url.action("someAction","someController")">...</a>` , it doesn't work?

Comment: I've just done a quick run in my test app and `@Url.Action("someAction", "someController")` seems to respect these settings.

Comment: and should it work for parameters too? like : `<a href="@url.action("someAction","someController",new{name=item.name})">...</a>` if name=Test it should translate it to **test** ?

Comment: @SepehrEstaki No, it doesn't affect any querystring parameters. MSDN: says _If a query string is included in the URL, that part of the URL is not converted to lower case._

Comment: then it is completely useless! for SEO!! , but AppendTrailingSlash also does not work for me too , does it just work for some URLs does not have querystring parameters ?!

Comment: Every one I've tried has worked OK for AppendTrailingSlash. Eg. that last one gave /somecontroller/someaction **/** ?name=Test

Comment: I thought it would adds a slash at the end of the Test!

Comment: @SepehrEstaki I've added these clarifications to the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused as to what these do.

In the case of `AppendTrailingSlash` all it does is add a `/` to the end of routes generated by MVC. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.appendtrailingslash(v=vs.110).aspx)

Similarly when you use `LowercaseUrls` it MVC will generate it's URLS in all lowercase. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.lowercaseurls(v=vs.110).aspx)

These will not do URL rewriting on the client side like your expecting.

Comment: what do you mean will not rewriting on the client side ? then where it rewrite ?!

Comment: When you use an HTML helper tag, like `@Html.ActionLink` that is where these changes get applied. When I say on the client side I mean the user browsing your website. These settings will not change the URL in his/her address.